# Watching vs. By watching

Tags: progressive-aspect

Today while watching TV, I came across this sentence,

> Don't waste this summer watching TV.

The sentence seemed weird to me because in English grammar if you want to use progressive tense then you should use *by, for, before, after* etc.  One more example:

> Puppy fell asleep sucking his thumb.

Shouldn't that sentence have been like this:

> Don't waste this summer **by** watching TV.

And the second one

> Puppy fell asleep **while** sucking his thumb.

But I am only new to English grammar. So if I am wrong, please elaborate.

Comment: The sentence is grammatical. *When you can take the train, why spend your time **driving**.*?  *He was allergic to the cat and spent the weekend **sneezing**.*  **by** would be grammatical as well in your example.  *The joke was so funny, he walked the whole way home **laughing**.*   But he did not walk home **by laughing**.

Comment: There's no mandatory rule to insert a preposition before the -ing form of a verb. Perhaps, if the -ing form is a noun (i.e., a gerund), you will typically need a preposition. "By watching TV, I learnt about WWII." _Watching_ here is a gerund noun: depending on usage, there may be a need for a preposition. "Watching TV, I learnt about WWII." Here, _watching_ is a present participle that modifies _I_: it doesn't need a preposition. [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/-ing#Distinction_between_gerunds_and_present_participles) has more information on this distinction.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use "by" or "while". These words can add meaning to a sentence but are not always necessary.

This sentence is correct and natural:

> Don't waste the summer watching TV.

Commenters have already given other examples:

> Why spend your time driving?
>
> He spent the whole weekend sneezing.
>
> He walked home laughing.

*By* gives the method used:

> He got to work by riding his bike.

*While* means "at the same time"

> He ate dinner while watching TV.

Using such words can reduce ambiguity, but they are not strictly required.

Compare

> I learnt about WWII while watching TV (I was studying and I had the TV on at the same time)
>
> I learnt about WWII by watching TV (I watched tv programs about the history of WWII)
>
> I learnt about WWII watching TV (ambiguous, but probably means the same as "by watching tv" in this context.)

Comment: You might check the first few lines of your answer for *literals*. A couple of slips indicate that you might have been in a hurry

Comment: Thanks Ronald, I've edited.  If you spot anything else, feel free to correct me.